# Amplify socket connection error while executing push or publish

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create a new environment for our app, and I go over the initial steps where you select the env name and those details. I run:

```
amplify env add mynewenv
```

But then, either `amplify push` or `amplify publish` won't work. I was able to get a good run for `amplify push` 2 or 3 times, but 90% of the time it failed. And `amplify publish` failed 100%. These are the two errors I got while running these commands:

- Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
  An error occurred during the push operation: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
- An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud
  write EPROTO
  An error occurred during the push operation: write EPROTO

I always get either one or the other, not both at the same time. Here is some information about my setup:

- SO: Ubuntu Mate Release 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit, Kernel Linux 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64, MATE 1.24.0
- Amplify version: 4.21.4
- npm version: 6.14.5
- aws --version: aws-cli/2.0.24 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.4.0-37-generic botocore/2.0.0dev28
- AWS Region: us-west-2
- node version: v14.4.0

I noticed something weird while running these amplify commands. This is an output from `speedtest-cli` *before* running `amplify push`:

```
Download: 50.30 Mbit/s
Upload: 5.91 Mbit/s
```

And this is an output *while* running `amplify push`:

```
Download: 8.30 Mbit/s
Upload: 0.72 Mbit/s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: @Carlos I stopped using amplify because of project needs. I was never able to execute this command from ubuntu. My guts tell me that from my Mac it will be a different story to tell. But although, I have a coworker who also runs on Mac and from time to time he sees this kind of connectivity problems.

Comment: I have been getting this error today in the Amplify deployment pipeline as well :/